# update a table using a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table t_time where I have the below attributes

```
time_key, calendar_dt, cal_year, cal_quarter, cal_month, cal_week, week_in_month, cal_st_dt_of_wk, cal_end_dt_of_wk, rfrsh_dt, cal_yyyymm

select * from t_time where time_key = (select max(time_key) from t_time);

74937   31-12-2015  2015    4   12  5   5   27-12-2015  02-01-2016  17-07-2009  201512
```

I want to write a stored proc such that when i specify the year,t_time should be inserted with all the keys and other attributes..

like

for 2016

```
time_key  calendar_dt cal_year  cal_quarter cal_month cal_week  week_in_month cal_st_dt_of_wk cal_end_dt_of_wk  rfrsh_dt  cal_yyyymm
74938       01-01-2016    2016        1           1         1             1         01-01-2016      02-01-2016    22-04-2015      201601
74939       02-01-2016    2016        1           1         1             1         01-01-2016      02-01-2016    22-04-2015      201601
74940       03-01-2016    2016        1           1         2             2         03-01-2016      09-01-2016    22-04-2015      201601
74941       04-01-2016    2016        1           1         2             2         03-01-2016      09-01-2016    22-04-2015      201601
```

cal_end_dt_of_wk is saturday of that week
cal_st_dt_of_wk is sunday of that week

can someone give me an idea to start with..

```
time_key -  time_key + 1
calendar_dt - select sysdate from dual;
cal_year    - select extract(year from sysdate) from dual;
cal_quarter - select case when extract(month from sysdate) in (1,2,3) then 1
                     case when extract(month from sysdate) in (4,5,6) then 2
                     case when extract(month from sysdate) in (7,8,9) then 3
                     case when extract(month from sysdate) in (10,11,12) then 4 else 0 end as cal_quarter from dual;
cal_month   - select extract(month from sysdate) from dual; 
cal_week    - select to_char(to_date(sysdate),'ww') from dual;  
week_in_month - select to_char(to_date(sysdate),'w') from dual;
cal_st_dt_of_wk -  select trunc(sysdate,'iw')-1 from dual;
cal_end_dt_of_wk - select trunc(sysdate,'iw')+5 from dual;
rfrsh_dt - select sysdate from dual;
cal_yyyymm - select to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's a lot of stuff ;) but I think this should work now:

```
-- provide year as YYYY
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fill_table (year IN VARCHAR2) IS
  date_holder DATE := TO_DATE ('01.01.' || year,'DD.MM.YYYY');
BEGIN
  WHILE (TO_CHAR (date_holder,'YYYY') = year) LOOP
  INSERT INTO t_time 
     VALUES (1, 
             date_holder,
             extract(year from date_holder), 
             case when extract(month from date_holder) in (1,2,3) then 1
                  when extract(month from date_holder) in (4,5,6) then 2
                  when extract(month from date_holder) in (7,8,9) then 3
                  when extract(month from date_holder) in (10,11,12) then 4 else 0 END, 
             extract(month from date_holder), 
             to_char(to_date(date_holder),'ww'),
             to_char(to_date(date_holder),'w'), 
             trunc(date_holder,'iw')-1,
             trunc(date_holder,'iw')+5,
             sysdate ,
             to_char(date_holder,'yyyymm'));

     date_holder := date_holder +1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

So the basic idea is:

- start with the `1.1.<YEAR>` date
- add one day by the other and insert values as you described

There seems to be an issue on the calendar week, week in month, start and end of week though .... anyway - the approach should be fine. I omitted the correct key calculation as well - best option would be a `SEQUENCE`.

***p.s.***: check [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f2fb/9).